# При компиляции выдает ошибку [Fatal Error] Unit4.pas(10): Internal error: SY576

Tags: delphi

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
[Fatal Error] Unit4.pas(10): Internal error: SY576
```

и выделяет строку

```
TForm4=class(TForm) ...
```

Делфи переустановила, все равно тоже самое. Помогите исправить. ((

Если ошибка в коде, то только тут:

```
procedure TForm4.Image2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    xls:=CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
    xls.Workbooks.Open('D:\Новая папка\Анкета.xlsx');
    xls.Range['A2']:=Edit1.Text;
    xls.Range['I3']:=Edit2.Text;
    xls.Range['A6']:=ComboBox1.Text;
    xls.Range['A8']:=ComboBox2.Text;
    if RadioButton1.Checked then 
        xls.Range['D3']:='Мужской'
    else 
        xls.Range['D3']:='Женский';
    xls.ActiveBook.SaveAs(ExtractFilePath(Application. ExeName) + Edit1.text+'.xlsx');
    xls.Visible:= True;
end;
```

Comment: @Вика1996, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать "rebuild", а не просто компиляцию. Если не получится, то зайдите в папку со своим проектом, удалите все dcu файлы и запустите компиляцию по-новому.

Answer (score 0):

Выйти из IDE, зайти снова. Все наладится.

Comment: Я думаю, что при переустановке делфи, c IDE выходили точно:) Хотя всякое, конечно, бывает.

Comment: @KoVadim, наши комментарии до перобразования в ответы дополняли друг друга. Системная ошибка. С ней бороться - значит перепробовать все. Винду перегрузить тоже туда входит. Что привело к ошибке не описано, значит работают общие рекомендации техподдержки :)

Comment: что привело к ошибке - написано. SY - это не от system, это от `SYmbol table`. А это обычно случается, если есть dcu, которые плохо скомпилировалось или, к примеру, кол-во имен переменных достигло критического значения.

Comment: @KoVadim, системная не от symbol table, да. системная в смысле что дельфа легла. dcu'ки закешировались криво, подвис эксель (раз сто) по ^F2 и т.д. всяко может быть. Опытные люди борются до решения проблемы, неопытные до первой неудачи.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы думаете, что ошибка на данном участке кода - установите на каждой строке брейкпоинты и по строчным запуском сможете локализировать ошибку (скорее всего). Для установки брейкпоинта нажмите мышью в редакторе кода левее нумерации строк. Должны появиться красные точки. Установите их напротив всех строк вышеприведенного кода.

Comment: это ошибка компиляции, а не выполнения. Поэтому, точки останова не помогут.